# Scrollable content in a mixed of table and flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

Please see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2g80r8br/5/).

I would like to have the table's 1st column respect its 90% width and have the user scroll left/right through items 1 to 3.  The `<td>` with "more" should always be displayed and not be part of the scroll.  In other words, I want to make the table's cell scroll.

How can I make the cell scroll its contained flex-box, while leaving the rest of the table static (i.e., not scrolling)?

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#flex-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 100%; /* This property is ignored */
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 30 px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <trow>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </trow>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <trow>
      <td style="width: 90%">
        <div id="flex-div">
          <div class="flex-item">1</div>
          <div class="flex-item">2</div>
          <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>more</td>
    </trow>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the table.

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```

For the table column width.

```
<colgroup>
  <col style="width: 90%;">
  <col>
</colgroup>
```

For the flexbox container.

```
#flex-div {
  ...
  overflow: auto;
}
```

For the flexbox item, set `min-width` or `flex-basic` instead of `width`.

```
.flex-item {
  ...
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

Also fix your HTML, change `<trow>` to `<tr>`.

---

**Final snippet**

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#flex-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col style="width: 90%;">
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <th>Header 2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="flex-div">
          <div class="flex-item">1</div>
          <div class="flex-item">2</div>
          <div class="flex-item">3</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>more</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Very close, but can you make the 1st column's width be 90%?

Comment: @JeffMatthews Use `colgroup` and `col` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **`min-width`** instead of **`width`** and set **`overflow:auto`**.

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#flex-div {
  display: flex;
  overflow: auto;
}

.flex-item {
  background-color: beige;
  padding: 30 px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <trow>
      <th style="width: 90%">Header 1</th>
      <th style="width: 10%">Header 2</th>
    </trow>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div id="flex-div">
          <div class="flex-item">1</div>
          <div class="flex-item">2</div>
          <div class="flex-item">3</div>
          <div class="flex-item">4</div>
          <div class="flex-item">5</div>
          <div class="flex-item">6</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>more</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```